# MySQL Date and Time functions don't exist

Tags: mysql, sqlite, function

I have installed [WampServer 2.0](http://www.wampserver.com/en/index.php) with MySQL 5.1.33.

I can do Numeric and String functions like

`SELECT ABS(-2)`
or
`SELECT LOWER('ASD')`

but with [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) such as

`SELECT CURDATE()`
or
`SELECT NOW()`

I get

```
Error : no such function: CURDATE
```

Am I doing something wrong, is there anything I need to install?

Any help about where to start investigating?

Comment: Did you try to reinstall WAMP? there may be an error in the installation.

Comment: @Adnan: Not yet. I would like to avoid that, but in case I find no other solution I will eventually have to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no error message from MySQL with the text "No such function."  I just did a grep on the whole source tree of MySQL 5.1, and that string does not occur anywhere (except in one comment).

My thought is that you aren't using MySQL, you're using SQLite.  Because I *can* reproduce that error when I run the SQLite command-line shell:

```
$ sqlite3
sqlite> select curdate();
Error: no such function: curdate
sqlite> select now();
Error: no such function: now
```

In SQLite, the [function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to get the current date is simply `date()`:

```
sqlite> select date();
2010-01-02
```

Comment: I was looking for something that would work between mysql and sqlite, and this was it.  Thanks!  FYI SQLite3 at least has datetime() as well, and the format matches the now() implementation from MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Many functions are different in SQlite and in MySQL (or any other product - if you except core functions, most functions provide the same functionality but with a different syntax). There is an open-source "compatibility library" implementing a large number of MySQL functions in SQLite [on the Kansas State University CIS website](http://sqlite-libs.cis.ksu.edu/)

Answer (score 0):

My inclination is to run a mysql repair install.  if that didn't work, then i'd try to wamp reinst.

Answer (score 0):

If SQLite had the same features as SQL, it would be amazing. But fortunately for query types with date comparisons it is possible to use existing SQLite functions.

An example of how I was able to carry out my query was as follows:
***Using an interface type class declaring my ObjectDAO: 'PartidoDAO'.***

```
@Query("select * from partido where fpartido>=DATE() and epartido = 'Santiago Bernabeu'  ORDER BY fpartido LIMIT 1")
    Partido getMoreRecentPartido();
```

If you want more information about functions related to date data types consult the web I invite you to consult this resource.
[SQLite Date Functions](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date-functions/).