# Select data from current month in android with SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

In my App I am trying to show balance for current month but I can't accomplish that.

This is my code

```
// Count Current Month Income
public float CurrentMonthIncome(){
    float x = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String getamountdata = "SELECT SUM(inc_amount) AS totalInc FROM "+ TABLE_ENTRY + " where year(entry_date)= year(CURDATE()) and MONTH(entry_date)=MONTH(CURDATE())";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(getamountdata, null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        x = c.getFloat(0);
    }
    return x;

}
```

When I execute that code, I get an exception like

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such function: CURDATE
Shutting down VM
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991697/mysql-date-and-time-functions-dont-exist) out. USE ` date()` instead of `CURDATE() OR NOW()`

Comment: It always helps to have [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) pinned as a bookmark.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to this [link](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)
use `date('now')` instead of `curdate()`.

In order to take current date, in MySQL and SQL Server, you can use `CURDATE()` but in SQLite, you don't have this option. To get current date, you have to use `date('now')` in your query to get the current date in that specific device.

So your query will be like this:

```
SELECT SUM(inc_amount) AS totalInc 
FROM "+ TABLE_ENTRY + " WHERE strftime('%Y',entry_date) = strftime('%Y',date('now')) AND  strftime('%m',entry_date) = strftime('%m',date('now'))
```

Comment: can you explain little more

Comment: sure :)
In order to take current date, in mysql and sql server, you can use `CURDATE()` but in sqlite, you don't have this option.

to get current date, you have to use `date('now')` in your query to get the current date in that specific device.

Comment: i am try to use this query: where strftime('%m', entry_date) = date('now') but not success.

Comment: not sure exactly....but I think your query would be like this:


`SELECT SUM(inc_amount) AS totalInc FROM "+ TABLE_ENTRY + " where strftime('%Y',entry_date)= strftime('%Y',date('now')) and strftime('%m',entry_date)=strftime('%m',date('now'))`

Comment: any luck?
let me know if u had any problems

Comment: yes, its working, thanks brother.

Comment: your welcome...please mark it as answer

Answer (score 1):

You are using SQLite not mySQL so in  SQLite the function to get the current date is

```
 date('now')
```

or

```
 datetime('now', 'localtime')
```

`CURDATE()` is a MySQL function. The same for function Month and Year that doesn't exist in SQLite. To get years and month you have to use:

```
strftime('%m', myDate)//to get Month
```

and

```
strftime('%Y', myDate)//  to get Year
```